# Getting Processor Information

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I have just ran `lshw` to get some information about  a machine I know nothing about, and I just wanted to confirm something.

Does this basically mean it is a dual core 64 bit processor that is installed?

```
*-logicalcpu:0
    description: Logical CPU      
    physical id: 0.1          
    width: 64 bits          
    capabilities: logical       
*-logicalcpu:1            
    description: Logical CPU           
    physical id: 0.2              
    width: 64 bits           
    capabilities: logical
```

Looking further down I see this

```
 *-cpu:1
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@1
      version: 6.7.6
      serial: 0001-0676-0000-0000-0000-0000
      size: 3150MHz
      capabilities: vmx ht
      configuration: id=0
    *-logicalcpu:0
         description: Logical CPU
         physical id: 0.1
         capabilities: logical
    *-logicalcpu:1
         description: Logical CPU
         physical id: 0.2
         capabilities: logical
```

Which makes me almost certain it is dual core but not convinced on the 64 bit.

Any help for this n00b would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might be wrong, but that looks more like a single core doing hyperthreading, which presents two "logical cores".

Comment: @Scaine Do you know if there is a way to confirm that?

Comment: I'm no expert on lshw, Toby, sorry.  I've amended my answer to reflect the output from my core2Duo processor (no hyperthreading).  Hope this helps.

Comment: what about a single command in the terminal?

Comment: **GUI:** tool: `sudo apt install hardinfo`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's often overlooked, so worth a shot.  Sorry if this is insultingly obvious :

[image: System Preferences]

Alt-F2, then `gnome-system-monitor`

Also, when I ran `sudo lshw | grep -i cpu`, I see a line which says cpus=2.

[image]

Comment: Ha, thanks - that **was** overlooked! That has listed two processors both Core 2 Duos @3.16GHz.  What it doesn't do it confirm if this is a 64 bit machine or not.. (or am I being dense and that fact is staring me in the face?)

Comment: `uname -r` should help with that, surely?  Or the same screenshot shows that I'm running 32-bit (my kernel is "generic").

Comment: I didn't set up the machine in the first place and I think the person who did erred on the site of caution and may have went for generic when they could have went higher.  Thanks so much for your help. I have all the information I need now!

Comment: Actually, `uname -m` tells you whether the OS is 64 bits or not. On a 64-bits machine, it returns `x86_64`.

Comment: I'd stick with generic myself, Toby.  Arguments for both sides... AGAINST : http://blog.pault.ag/post/3107062816/why-64-bit-computing-is-really-dumb-right-now and FOR : http://jldugger.livejournal.com/41896.html.  Unless you're a developer or heavy power user video editor type thingymajig... 32-bit is fine for a while longer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn : Never knew that!  You learn something new every day!

Comment: @Scaine: 64 bits vs 32 bits is an off-topic discussion here. 64 bits applications cannot run on a 32 bits OS, but the reverse is possible. As 64 bits is the future (even if it is available since 2000), I'll stick to an 64 bits OS and recommend others 64 bits as well.

Comment: Horses for courses.  I'm with you actually - the next build I do will be 64-bit, but all I'm saying is that 32-bit is still very much alive and kicking.  But you're quite right.  This *is* OT.  :-)

Comment: If you stick with 32bit, at least use the -generic-pae kernel so you can get access to all your memory and gain the NX bit for security.

Comment: my system monitor doesnt have this tab :-(

Comment: I am using remote server

Comment: How do I do it using a temrinal

Comment: That is no longer part of the System monitor. Now you can go `Settings  -> Details` to see hardware info.

Comment: @hat, yes! `Settings -> About` for me!

Answer (score 145):

To get the Processor model use the below command in a terminal.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
```

To get the information about number of processors

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep process| wc -l
```

Comment: For future Googlers - this command doesn't work on ARM processors as the output is very different in at least 18.04.  The `lscpu` command below works well.

Comment: `grep` could handle files as well as stdout, so you could simplify it like this: `grep name /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`

Answer (score 121):

The simplest way to do this is to use the command created for that, **`lscpu`**:

```
user@host:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 55
Model name:            Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2840  @ 2.16GHz
Stepping:              8
CPU MHz:               697.301
CPU max MHz:           2582,3000
CPU min MHz:           499,8000
BogoMIPS:              4331.60
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             24K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep
mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm
pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl 
xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor 
ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt  
tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb tpr_shadow vnmi 
flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat
```

This command will tell you your chipset's characteristics as well as any supported instructions (or flags) in an easy-to-use and simple-to-read manner.

Comment: better answer here!

Answer (score 10):

In ubuntu 14.04 desktop, the system monitor tool no longer has a "System" tab.  You should see roughly the same screen like this:

1. click the settings wheel
   (to clarify: the taskbar icon in the absolute upper-right hand corner of the screen: [image])
2. choose "About this Computer"

Comment: Sorry, what is the 'settings wheel'?

Comment: @DenisGolomazov - sorry, i just edited the answer to explain

Comment: This no longer works on Ubuntu 16.  You need to click on the item title "Details" from the "System Settings"

Comment: work for me ubuntu 16.04 at top of the menu

Answer (score 4):

**You can just use this** : `more /proc/cpuinfo` in your command line.

**Then you faced with something like this :**

[image]

**You can use this for more information :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Hardware Lister application (*lshw-gtk*) from the default Ubuntu repositories is a user-friendly GUI application that displays detailed information about your computer's hardware including the model name and architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) of the CPU.

Simply select a category to obtain detailed information about a hardware component from the main interface.

[image: Hardware Lister]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `uname -m` or `arch` command from the terminal.

For a 64-bit processor and kernel, the command will output `x86_64`.

Comment: Those commands output "x86_64" which identifies that 64-bit software is being used. However, it doesn't answer question of whether or not there is a dual core processor. Using `sudo lshw -class CPU` will provide model number of processor which can be googled to get full specifications of that chip which could be single core, hyper-threaded.

Comment: Note, though, that with this result, your system will not output `x86_64` if you do not have the 64-bit kernel installed on your system.

Comment: Thank you @KazWolfe for the edit. I was searching for this answer to run some Benchmarking suites on different processors, and came across these commands.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is from `Launcher` select `System Settings`-->`Details`:

[image: System Settings About]

This identifies both your CPU model number and whether 32-bit or 64-bit software is running. It also displays other useful information such as amount of RAM.

Now take your CPU model number in google search engine type `3630QM number of cores`:

[image: 3630QM number of cores]

Replace `3630QM` with the model number you get from the first display.

All the other answers are great answers but if you really want the "simplest" way of doing this I believe this is the preferred method without opening a terminal session or installing new software.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1 | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs`